SwiftUI Alert With Countdown - How to Dynamically Update Variable Used in Alert
In my SwiftUI view below, I would like my alert to update with the countdown variable which controls whether or not the Proceed button is active & also shows up in the text of the alert itself.
The current implementation does not update the value of countdown - it always remains as 5.
struct RedemptionView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var showQRCodeScanner = false
    @State private var showPasscodeView = false
    @State private var billAmount: String = ""
    @State private var isShowingRedemptionStepView = false
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State fileprivate var countdown: Int = 5

    
    var allowsDelitePointCollection: Bool
    var voucherTitle: String
    var discountId: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DismissButton()

            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                Text("Scan the QR code provided by the staff, or pass your phone to them to enter the staff code.")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                
                Button(action: {
                    if !billAmount.isEmpty {
                        showAlert = true
                        startCountdown()
                    } else {
                        showQRCodeScanner = true
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Scan QR Code")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            hideKeyboard()
        }
        .padding(.top, 20)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showQRCodeScanner) {
            QRCodeScannerView(discountId: discountId, billAmount: billAmount, discountTitle: voucherTitle, isPresented: $isShowingRedemptionStepView)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPasscodeView) {
            PasscodeView(billAmount: billAmount, discountId: discountId, discountTitle: voucherTitle, isPresented: $isShowingRedemptionStepView)
        }
        .onChange(of: isShowingRedemptionStepView) { oldValue, newValue in
            if !newValue && oldValue {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        .alert("Verify Bill Amount - \(priceToStrFormat(price: (Int(billAmount) ?? 0) * 100, useComma: false))", isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Button("Proceed\(countdown > 0 ? " In \(countdown)s" : "")") {
                if countdown == 0 {
                    showQRCodeScanner = true
                }
            }.disabled(countdown > 0)
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
            } message: {
                Text("Show Phone to Staff to verify bill amount. Proceed in \(countdown) seconds")
            }
    }


    private func startCountdown() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            if countdown > 0 {
                countdown -= 1
            } else {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}


See Update text inside alert message

Does this answer your question? Update text inside alert message

The previous API (Alert) for alerts in SwiftUI used to support this, but that is now deprecated. The new modifier(alert(_:isPresented:presenting:actions:message:)) added to replace Alert doesn't have capability to update presented alert's content.
